# Closing Layout Drawer

Tags: material-design-lite

How do you close/hide the layout drawer in a supported way? Up to version 1.0.6 I've been closing the drawer by removing the 'is-visible' class from it. Starting with version 1.0.6 this no longer works properly. The semi-transparent obfuscator div doesn't always clear when you close the drawer.

I tried to raise this as a bug but apparently the team doesn't support closing the drawer at all aside from clicking outside of it.

You can see a very simple example here:  http://jsbin.com/tajedahexi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 5):

You can do this. Its a hack.

```js
document.body.querySelector('.mdl-layout__obfuscator.is-visible').click();
//or
document.querySelector('.mdl-layout').MaterialLayout.drawerToggleHandler_();
```

There is the MaterialLayout drawerToggleHandler_ method it is marked as private. But you could use it. It would do the same.
[Material Lite Source, drawerToggleHandler](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/v1.0.6/material.js#L3234)

Comment: I know the workaround. I was looking for a supported way of doing it.

Comment: There is no supported way. You can use the method material-lite uses. But its marked as private method. I posted the link where you can find the method if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

Since I posted this question Google has added a public method to toggle the drawer:

```
var layout = document.querySelector('.mdl-layout'); // Get layout reference
layout.MaterialLayout.toggleDrawer();
```

Once the version containing that change was released I implemented the official method successfully.

Comment: Don't know if I'm just lazy, but I can't seem to find in the documents?